# Vim: Portable way to edit "[1]" when "1" exists

Tags: bash, vim, cmd, cygwin

So, I want to edit the file `[1]`. Problem is, I also have a file called `1`. I also use cygwin and its `bash` shell, win32 `cmd` and Linux. Sometimes I use cygwin's `vim`, and sometimes I use the win32 `vim` and `gvim`.

I can find no consistent way of opening the file `[1]`. Often `vim` will see `[1]` as a file glob, and open `1` instead.

In linux, `:e [1]` fails, but `:e \[1]` works. In win32, `:e \[1]` fails.

I seem to be stuck in a twisty maze of passages involving `fnameescape()`, the `shellslash` and `isfname` options, and win32 `vim`'s attempt to handle `\` as a path separator.

**Ah ha!**

`:e [[]1]` seems to work(?). Surely there is some "official" way (like calling a vim function) of getting to this pattern? (**Edit**: No, this only works when `[1]` *already* exists. Sigh.)

**EDIT**

After Ingo Karkat's answer, My file-loading bash script now has this snippet in it:

```
# Double single quotes are single quotes in a single-quoted vim string (got that?)
FILE=${FILE//\'/\'\'}
[[ -n $FILE ]] && gvim -u NONE -U NONE -f --remote-send '<c-\><c-n>:let b = bufwinnr('\'"$FILE"\'')|if b != -1|exec b "wincmd w"|else|new `='\'"$FILE"\''`|endif<cr>'
gvim -u NONE -U NONE -e -s --cmd 'let a = remote_foreground("GVIM")|q'
```

Comment: Could just let vim/bash/cmd autocomplete the path name by tabbing through the options. That's what I do  when I have an impossible path name to type.

Comment: @Tom: Doesn't work. `gvim '[1]'` in cygwin bash with win32 gvim. Gvim correctly gets `[1]` but then matches the pattern against plain unadorned `1`.

Comment: Does it work if you escape the right bracket as well: `:e \[1\]`?

Comment: `:e .` and select from the menu.

Comment: @n.m. Doesn't work. I select `[1]` and gvim dutifully opens `1`. Besides, I really want to get this working from a script.

Comment: @Thor: Win32 gvim sees that as the file `]` in folder `/[1/`

Comment: It's clearly a bug then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is:

```
:edit `='[1]'`
```

This (mis?-)uses backtick expansion as a Vim expression (`` :help `= ``). The downside is that the pattern is now susceptible to filtering with the `'wildignore'` option.

We once had a [lengthy discussion of this issue](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/1476bde8469404ea/6c4b27d92c70c6da); but it somehow fizzled out without any action taken. So currently, literal use of filenames which also can be interpreted as a file glob is hairy, and most plugins handle this badly (mine included), because the unanimous advice in the help is to use `fnamescape()`, which doesn't handle this.

Comment: This variant is failing with `\n` in filenames, meaning that there is no unified way to escape any filename (`=["a\nb"]` is also failing, even though it would be logical to have it working).

Comment: Still a great tip though. TVM. How on earth does it work? Just some wild chance that backticks do not go through wildcard expansion? Where can I vote for some feature to load literal file names?

Comment: @ZyX: Is your inner perfectionist urging you to point out such pathological cases, or are you a masochist and actually use such weird file names :-)

Comment: @bobbogo: That's a special Vim feature. You could post on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) and complain about this, but without a compelling patch attached, it's unlikely to spur any change. I'd prefer an extra `fnamescape()` parameter or extra function to escape file globs, too; this feels way cleaner than the clever use of the backtick expression.

Comment: @ZyX: Yes, I use such filenames. They are produced by various horrible scripts. Vim is unreasonable in its handling of such things.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Extra parameter won’t fix the issue (as it requires all plugins to change). By the way, `fnameescape()` not just fails to escape `[a-z]` properly, it ignores `$VAR` on windows (i.e. `fnameescape('$VAR')` yields `$VAR`, but `$VAR` is expanded). You need to change the way filnames are parsed to actually escape anything. Or just make \`=["abc\ndef[a-z]"]\` be always intepreted as one filename, regardless of `'wildignore'` and others. Maybe use \`!{expr}\` specifically for scripts (which will always treat `{expr}` as one filename) and make `fnameescape` output this.

Comment: Plugins have to change, anyway; hardly any is using the backtick expression today (because the help only mentions and recommends `fnameescape()`). If plugins have to change, I'd rather have a straightforward function than a backtick solution. No matter how you do the syntax, it'll always be cryptic and non-intuitive.

Comment: @IngoKarkat And about filenames: I do not use them, but I constantly see zip archives with russian filenames within unpacking to all sorts of crap filenames. I also used to have accidentally created such filenames (by pasting string with embedded newlines to konqueror when renaming file). `[…]` and any other kind of special character is common to see when it comes to anime subtitles. `*.*` is a real directory name present on my filesystem: when I only came from windows (to avoid having to see a bunch of `.progname` everything was put to this directory) (now it is only a symlink to `a.a`).

Comment: Why do they do? `fnameescape` is said to escape filenames for such cases, and it must escape them properly without additional arguments. What I suggest is rather then trying to fix  `\ ` handling in filenames (which is likely to be incompatible thus not accepted) introduce `\`!{expr}\`` expansion and make `fnameescape("$HOME\\\n\\*.*")` output `\`!"$HOME\\\n\\*.*"\``» on windows that should expand to one file name. **NOT** make plugins use `\`!`, make `fnameescape()` use new `\`!` instead.

Comment: @ZyX: Ah, thanks for the explanation. I still think `fnameescape()` users need to indicate somehow what they want; it is also used e.g. in a wrapper around `:args`, where you want to keep any passed file globs and pass them as-is. What should be the new default depends on backwards compatibility and perceived usage proportion. Any way, we need a proposed patch on vim_dev!

Comment: @IngoKarkat Never needed such wrapper. Don’t you use `glob` and `:exe "args" join(map(…, 'fnameescape(v:val)'))` for this? What I really needed is a function which takes a list of files and a glob and returns a list of matched files. I have now reread and can say that `fnameescape()` output depending on `'isfname'` while processing of arguments (OP question may have been answered “remove `[` from 'isfname'” if not another bug: `e C:\\[a-z]` tries to open file `C:[a-z]` now) is err… very strange design decision.

Comment: @ZyX What about young Moolenaar's suggestion for a command modifier, `:nowild e [1]` say?

Comment: @bobbogo It has the same problem as additional argument to fnameescape: it requires scripts to be changed. And it is also making `fnameescape()` useless (mainly because due to bug mentioned above it cannot be used reliably; `\`!` should fix this as well).

Comment: @ZyX Well, one problem with `fnameescape` is that there seems to be no way to escape `[1]` so that it will be opened by `:e`. There needs to be some way of telling `:e` not to glob its parameter.

Comment: @bobbogo Is not it what I am talking about? But you *don’t* need a way of telling `:e` not to glob-expand its parameter. You *do* need make `fnameescape()` be able to escape globs. Else you are having a bunch of plugins that are not working because they were written before `noglob` was introduced and *two* things that are required to use when you want to open random filename. Do you thing that having to write `:if exists(':noglob') | execute 'noglob e' fnameescape(file) | else | execute 'e' fnameescape(file) | endif` at least until next major release is good?

Comment: @ZyX What output can `fnameescape` give to work with `:e`, when there is nothing that I can type manually? (I am still mystified as to how `\`=` does its magic.)

Comment: @bobbogo Were you reading at all? I made two suggestions: add `\`!{expr}\`` expansion, make `fnameescape()` use ***expansion proposed for addition***. Not something *currently* existing, something what *is to be added*.